# xsl conversion attributes to elements

Tags: xml, xslt

i just want the follwing output. Here is the xml code, and also the otput. So i just want the same output which i have given.

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<acta>
   <sessió>68</sessió>
   <data>2016-11-21</data>
   <inici>20:00:00</inici>
   <durada>pT3H45M</durada>
   <comunitat> Junta de propietaris del Carrer de la Selva de Mar, 211 </comunitat>
   <president>Sr. Lluís Bendito i Sigüenza</president>
   <vicepresident>Sra. Ramona González Remolona</vicepresident>
   <administrador>Sr. Romualdo Malandrín Segura</administrador>
</acta>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="actaampliada.css" ?>
<!-- Aquest document ha estat generat amb el prodigiós programa ManualTypemàtic v0.1 -->
<acta sessió="68" data="2016-11-21" inici="20:00:00" durada="pT3H45M" >
    <comunitat> Junta de propietaris del Carrer de la Selva de Mar, 211 </comunita                                                                                      t>
    <president>Sr. Lluís Bendito i Sigüenza</president>
    <vicepresident>Sra. Ramona González Remolona</vicepresident>
    <administrador>Sr. Romualdo Malandrín Segura</administrador>
    <assistents>
        <assistent>
            <pis>1er 1ra</pis>
            <veí>Sra. Josefa Ramos Granados</veí>
            <veí>Sra. Jamilda Altramuz Izaguirre</veí>
        </assistent>
        <assistent>
            <pis>1er 2na</pis>
            <veí>Sr. Vicent Carallot i Gripau</veí>
        </assistent>
        <assistent>
            <pis>2on 1ra</pis>
            <veí rol="president">Sr. Lluís Benito i Sigüenza</veí>
        </assistent>
        <assistent>
            <pis>2on 2na</pis>
            <veí>Sr. Carles Valdaura Ronyós</veí>
            <veí rol="vicepresident">Sra. Ramona González Remolona</veí>
            <veí>Sta. Ramona Valdaura González</veí>
        </assistent>
        <assistent>
            <pis>4rt 1ra</pis>
            <veí>Sr. Lam Kam Chuen</veí>
        </assistent>
    </assistents>
    <noassistents>
        <pis>3er 2na</pis>
        <pis>3er 1ra</pis>
        <pis>4rt 2na</pis>
    </noassistents>
    <ordredeldia>
        <punt id="1">Lectura i aprovació, si escau, de l'acta anterior</punt>
        <punt id="2">Estat de pagament de les quotes del propietari del pis 4rt 2n                                                                                      a.</punt>
        <punt id="3">Torn obert de paraula</punt>
        <punt id="4">Horari de reg i utilització dels espais comuns per part del p                                                                                      ropietari del pis 4rt 2na.</punt>
    </ordredeldia>
    <desenvolupament>
        <entrada punt="1">
            <paragraf>La sra. vicepresidenta llegeix l’acta de la reunió.</paragra                                                                                      f>
        </entrada>
        <entrada punt="2">
            <paragraf>El sr. president passa la paraula al Sr. administrador qui d                                                                                      escriu que el pis 4rt 2na no està al corrent de pagament de les quotes de la comun                                                                                      itat. Indica que el propietari en qüestió va deixar de pagar fa cinc mesos i deu a                                                                                       la comunitat 376.25€.</paragraf>
            <paragraf>El sr. Vicent Carallot exposa els problemes que està tenint                                                                                       amb el reg de les plantes a qualsevol hora i de manera desproporcionada, per part                                                                                       del propietari del pis en qüestió i també que deixa una pudor inaguantable a la po                                                                                      rteria quan baixa les escombreries. Altres veïns s’hi afegeixen a la discussió.</p                                                                                      aragraf>
            <paragraf>El sr. Chin Pun indica que l’ascensor no arriba al seu pis o                                                                                       bé que s’ha comprat un gos verd (cap de la junta ni el Sr. administrador vam pode                                                                                      r esverinar-ho exàctament). En tot cas, se li indica que aquest tema havia de ser                                                                                       tractat al torn obert de paraula.</paragraf>
        </entrada>
        <entrada punt="4">
            <paragraf>Queda tractat amb el punt 2.</paragraf>
        </entrada>
        <entrada punt="3">
            <paragraf>No queda temps per desenvolupar aquest punt. El sr. Cho Chin                                                                                       protesta i la junta acorda oferir-li una oportunitat per a exposar el seu tema en                                                                                       una reunió propera.</paragraf>
        </entrada>
    </desenvolupament>
    <acords>
      <acord id="1">S'acorda abordar el tema del Sr. Chin Pun en la propera reunió                                                                                      </acord>
    </acords>
    <temespendents>
      <tema id="1"> Estudi del problema del veí del 4rt 1ra </tema>
    </temespendents>
</acta>
```

I have tried this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Demostració de conversió d'atributs a elements -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="acta">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="acta/@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the problem is that i get only the attributes in elements, i also want the follwing tags in the `<acta>`: `<comunitat> <president> <vicepresident> <administrador>`, AS YOU CAN SEE IN THE OUTPUT. And i want no more tags, nothing else. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close with your attempt. However, what I would do is start with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copying) and override what's needed...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Identity transform-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Convert attributes of acta to elements.-->
  <xsl:template match="acta/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Remove children of acta when they also contain child elements.-->
  <xsl:template match="acta/*[*]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: I made the assumption that any child of `acta` that contains child elements should be removed. If this is not a safe assumption, let me know I can update the stylesheet if needed.

Comment: Can you explain the "<xsl:template match="/acta/*[*]"/>" please?

Comment: @Abdullah - Sure. This part of the match: `acta/*` matches all child elements of `acta`. The predicate `[*]` tests for child elements. So the template matches if an element is a child of `acta` and also has child elements of its own. For example, `assistents` matches because it's a child of `acta` and has `assistent` children. Since the template is empty, nothing is output and no other processing happens for that element.

Comment: This might help with the use of `*` (abbreviated syntax) and `[]` (predicates): https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-path-expressions

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is that i get only the attributes in elements, i also
>   want the follwing tags in the `<acta>`: `<comunitat> <president> <vicepresident> <administrador>`, AS YOU CAN SEE IN THE OUTPUT. And i
>   want no more tags, nothing else.

If you know exactly which elements you want, why not list them explicitly - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/acta">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="comunitat | president | vicepresident | administrador"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```